# XML translate through XSL when tags contain encoded characters

Tags: xml, xslt

UPDATE: Failing cases

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire &amp; Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>   
</catalog>
```

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire & Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>   
</catalog>
```

Hi I have a following XML

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>   
</catalog>
```

The following XSL to translate the above

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Upto now the translation happens fine. However, if I change the XML  tag value to contain an encoded character like `&` or `&amp;` I am not getting a result

How can I escape these characters?

Comment: Can you show us sample input that actually fails? And show us exactly how it fails?

Comment: If you have &amp; in input, it should work with your created XSLT.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<catalog>
 <cd>
  <title>Empire & Burlesque</title>
  <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
  <country>USA</country>
  <company>Columbia</company>
  <price>10.90</price>
  <year>1985</year>
 </cd>

Comment: You can edit your question, instead of sticking it into the comments like this.

Comment: @ Navin I tryied this: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<catalog>
 <cd>
  <title>Empire &amp; Burlesque</title>
  <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
  <country>USA</country>
  <company>Columbia</company>
  <price>10.90</price>
  <year>1985</year>
 </cd> 
</catalog> But it failes

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `&` to `&amp;`, that should work fine. Since it looks like you have already tried this. You could try `&#38;` and `&#x26;` which are the decimal and hexadecimal unicode references to the `&` character respectively.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<catalog> 
  <cd> 
    <title>Empire &#x26; or &#38; Burlesque</title> 
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist> 
    <country>USA</country> 
    <company>Columbia</company> 
    <price>10.90</price> 
    <year>1985</year> 
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

If that doesn't fix it, may I know which XSLT processor is used to produce the output?

Comment: No this is not working for me. I this an issue with encoding="ISO-8859-1" or should I handle it within XSL?

Comment: No ISO-8859-1 seems ok, it works fine here using .Net MSXML 4.0. So which XSLT processor are you using? Search for processors [on this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) if you don't know the answer.

Comment: I am just trying the http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog

Comment: In that case, what you are running into is a problem with the way they are reading their data out of their `<textarea>`. If you try any other encoded character, like `&quot;` it works just fine. They are posting the form to the results page, something in that process must be doing something to `&`s and `&amp;`s.

Comment: I think the posting of the form reads both a single `&` and an `&amp;` out as a `&` into the post data, which would result in invalid post data, as a `&` in post data means the start of a new parameter.